# I have created an Flutter app and i want to connect it to a node js web application that is not published

Tags: flutter

I have the endpoints of the web application but i dont know how to find the url to connect.I know the server the database the web application uses is in

I tried to use localhost but since it isnt locally it didnt work.How do i find the url that i need to use to connect?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I recommend you to use the port forwarding approach.

Several free services, such as Serveo, Ngrok, LocalTonet, and LocalTunnel, can facilitate this process.

With this method, you run your Node server locally on port 3000. To make your localhost accessible to the public, use the command to forward your port to

```
Serveo.
ssh -R mbapi.serveo.net:80:localhost:3000 serveo.net

Localhost Run.
ssh -R 80:localhost:3000 localhost.run
```

then it gives you a url like this

[image]

Edit
please make sure sure you changed the mbapi in the above command.